# DataDriven MSTests CSV with semicolon separator

Tags: visual-studio, csv, data-driven-tests

I'm trying to make a datadriven test using Visual Studio.
My issue is that it uses coma separator by default.
As I work using a french environment, the system separator for csv is semicolon.
Is there a way to specify the separator in the datasource ?

Here is my Test :

```
[DataSource("Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.DataSource.CSV", "Test.csv", "Test#csv", Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting.DataAccessMethod.Sequential)]
[DeploymentItem(@"Test.csv")]
public void Test()
{
}
```

If I use coma for separator, I can't modify the file using MS Excel without configuration.
If I use semicolon, the datarow is not split.

I don't want to modify system properties.

Answer (score 1):

It may be a bit late, but I'll still answer because it might help others.

Under the covers, Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.DataSource.CSV uses the OleDb driver. The data source you described is equal to

```csharp
[DataSource("System.Data.OleDb", 
    "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source=.; Extended Properties=\"Text\"",
    "Test#csv",
     Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting.DataAccessMethod.Sequential)]
```

Once you know this, you know you can also use a **schema.ini** file with this content, to set the delimiter.

```ini
[Test.csv]
Format=Delimited(;)

[SomeOtherTableToShowYouOnlyHaveToCreateOneSchemaDotIni.csv]
Format=Delimited(;)
```

**IMPORTANT** this file needs to be ANSI or UTF-8 *without* Byte Order Mark (BOM). By default, Visual studio creates text files *with* this mark. In Visual Studio, the "save as" dialog contains the option to export the file as US-ASCII, which should be sufficient.

Last thing you need to do, is to include the ini as deployment item:

```csharp
[DataSource("Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.DataSource.CSV",
    "Test.csv", 
    "Test#csv",
    DataAccessMethod.Sequential)]
[DeploymentItem(@"Test.csv")]
[DeploymentItem(@"schema.ini")]
public void Test()
{ ... }
```

By the way: this does NOT work:

```csharp
[DataSource("System.Data.OleDb", 
    "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source=.; Extended Properties=\"Text;FMT=Delimited(;)\"",
    "Test#csv",
     Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting.DataAccessMethod.Sequential)]
```